# Android Market: Making my app "free"

Tags: android, google-play

The help text on the publishing section says that once I make my app free I can no longer make it a commercial product. Is this true? Can I simply delete everything and re-publish my app to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its true that if you make your app free, you can't make it paid anymore. If you do want to make a paid version while you have a free version, you'll have to upload a **new** app with a **different** package name. You probably can't just delete everything and republish.